# Mounting LVM2 volume with XFS filesystem

Tags: data-recovery, xfs, lvm2

Unfortunately I'm not able to access the data on my NAS anymore. I can't figure out why this is the case as I haven't changed anything. So I plugged one of the harddisks in my computer to access the data. What I did:

```
kpartx -a /dev/sdc
```

Now I should be able to access

```
/dev/mapper/vg001-lv001
```

When trying to mount it I get:

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/mapper/vg001-lv001 /home/user/mnt
mount: /dev/mapper/vg001-lv001: can't read superblock
```

Now I did a

```
parted -l
```

which gave me

```
Modell: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Festplatte  /dev/mapper/vg001-lv001:  498GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B
Partitionstabelle: loop

Number  Begin   End    Size  Filesystem  Flags
 1      0,00B   498GB  498GB  xfs
```

Does anybody have a solution how to recover the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

Making a copy of the partition

```
sudo ddrescue -b512 /dev/mapper/vg001-lv001 /somewhere/backup.iso ~/logfile.txt
```

After doing a

```
xfs_check /somewhere/backup.iso
```

it said that the journal is broken so

```
xfs_repair -L /somewhere/backup.iso
```

did the job! It is now possible to mount the filesystem again by

```
mount -o loop /somewhere/backup.iso /mnt/disk
```